# Django: Display contents of txt file on the website

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have this in my views.py

```
def read_file(request):
    f = open('path/text.txt', 'r')
    file_contents = f.read()
    print (file_contents)
    f.close()
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^impala/$', views.people, name='impala'),
]
```

I am not seeing anything on the website (text.txt file has information).
I also don't see any output in the terminal and there are no errors.

Comment: what is in your ``urls.py``? Furthermore, you don't have ``context`` defined. Which leads me to the assumption that you are not wiring your function based view to a route.

Comment: @YannicHamann please see edit. I also have base.html in my templates that i inherited in index.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have the function `read_file` in your `views.py` adjust your `urls.py` to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^test/$', views.read_file, name='test'),
    url(r'^impala/$', views.people, name='impala'),
]
```

Fix your function based view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def read_file(request):
    f = open('path/text.txt', 'r')
    file_content = f.read()
    f.close()
    return HttpResponse(file_content, content_type="text/plain")
```

Spin up up your development server and visit `localhost:port/test`. You should see the content of `test.txt`.

If you want to pass the content of the text file to your `template.html` add it to the `context` variable and access it in your template with [`{{ file_content }}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#variables).

```
def read_file(request):
    f = open('path/text.txt', 'r')
    file_content = f.read()
    f.close()
    context = {'file_content': file_content}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Keep in mind that a web server like `nginx` or `apache` would normally take care of serving static files for performance reasons.

Comment: I succeed with localhost:port/test, I do see the text from my file. trying to  get it to show up on the main site

Comment: What you mean by main site? Do you want to change the url or wire it to your template?

Comment: Sorry, i meant wire it to my template. Still unable to do that, I have the variable in my template but nothing is showing

Comment: You can add ``{% debug %}`` to your template to view the content of the current context.

Comment: @YannicHamann when i added `{% debug %}` i get this error .  `{'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'ERROR': 40, 'INFO': 20, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'WARNING': 30}, 'csrf_token': ._get_val at 0x10dd11268>>, `

Answer (score 0):

you can pass content of your file as a string to your html template

```
def read_file(request):
    f = open('path/text.txt', 'r')
    file_contents = f.read()
    f.close()
    args = {'result' : file_contents }
    return render(request, "index.html", context, args)
#######################index.html


   
<HTML>
 ...
   <BODY>
      <P>{{ result }} </p>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```