# Can my django website run other scripts that interact with the same database?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am wanting to run another script (from within the django app?) that can parse some text files to put values into the mysql database my django website uses.  Then a webpage loads it would grab those values and display them.   I am not sure the right way to go about this, ideally I can just create a python script that runs as a cron job and does standard mysql stuff to get and change the data in the same table the django app reads, or is there a more django way to do this?  from within the django app?  I am not sure how to run scripts 'on the side' or 'like a cron job' from within django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a management commaand [(Documentation).](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) Then

```
./manage.py mycommand --myoption  foo.txt
```

Or whatever you want to define as its interface, and invoke it in cron.

There's also a third-party [django-cron](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) app (which I know about but can't vouch for). Also check [django-packages](https://djangopackages.org/) site (put cron in the search box, there are quite a few matches)

Comment: Cool the kind of starter info I was looking for ty!

Comment: Additionally I found this which might be a better choice?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016255/django-display-contents-of-txt-file-on-the-website. Since I realized the data changes often.